# Executing PowerShell with Terraform Extension in Azure

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I am attempting to execute a PowerShell script using azurerm_virtual_machine_extension, and I'm experiancing an error.

Here is my code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "win_vmext" {                                                                                                                                                                                   
  name                  = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windows_vm.name                                                                                                                                                                    
  virtual_machine_id    = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windows_vm.id                                                                                                                                                                      
  publisher             = "Microsoft.Compute"                                                                                                                                                                                                
  type                  = "CustomScriptExtension"                                                                                                                                                                                            
  type_handler_version  = "1.10"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  settings = <<SETTINGS                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe ./winrm.ps1"                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
SETTINGS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

The winrm.ps1 is located in my Terraform execution path.

The resource will fail, and I see this output in the CustomScriptHandler.txt log file:

> [ERROR] Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. The command had an error output of: './winrm.ps1 : The term './winrm.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
> operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

If I log into the instance and execute it locally, it works fine. I have tried a few variations on the command to no avail.

Comment: If the script is to be located via the `PATH` environment variable, don't use `./`: `powershell.exe winrm.ps1` (short for: `powershell.exe -Command winrm.ps1` - do _not_ use `-File` in this case).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @mklement0. I ran it with powershell.exe -Command winrm.ps1, and I get the same error: "The term 'winrm.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: That implies that the directory in which `winrm.ps1` is located is _not_ in `$env:PATH`, so you'll either have to add it or invoke the script with its _full path_. If you expect `winrm.ps1` to be in the _current_ directory,  yet invocation with `./winrm.ps1` fails, the implication is that it's not actually there.

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to execute a PowerShell script using azurerm_virtual_machine_extension & got the output without any error.

I have referred the code from this [official Microsoft document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-on-azure-vms-with-terraform/ba-p/3827573) by @[Vinicius Apolinario](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/26192) and modified with my variables.

**main.tf**

```
    terraform {

required_providers {

azurerm  =  {

source  =  "hashicorp/azurerm"

version  =  "=3.57.0"

}

}

}

provider  "azurerm" {

features {

}

}

#Creates the Azure Resource Group

resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "rg" {

name  =  var.resource_group

location  =  var.location

}

#Creates the Azure Virtual Network

resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "vnet" {

name  =  "v-bolliv-vnet"

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

address_space  =  ["192.168.10.0/24"]

}
#Creates the subnet

resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "testvmsubnet" {

name  =  "v-bolliv-subnet"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

virtual_network_name  =  azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name

address_prefixes  =  ["192.168.10.0/24"]

}
#Creates a vNIC for the VM

resource  "azurerm_network_interface"  "dc01_nic" {

name  =  "dc01_nic"

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

ip_configuration {

name  =  "dc01_nic"

subnet_id  =  azurerm_subnet.testvmsubnet.id

private_ip_address_allocation  =  "Dynamic"

}

}

#Creates the Azure VM

resource  "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine"  "dc01" {

name  =  "DC01"

resource_group_name  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

location  =  azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

size  =  "Standard_D4s_v3"

admin_username  =  var.win_username

admin_password  =  var.win_userpass

network_interface_ids  =  [

azurerm_network_interface.dc01_nic.id

]

  

os_disk {

caching  =  "ReadWrite"

storage_account_type  =  "Standard_LRS"

}

  

source_image_reference {

publisher  =  "MicrosoftWindowsServer"

offer  =  "WindowsServer"

sku  =  "2022-Datacenter"

version  =  "latest"

}

}

  

#Install Active Directory on the DC01 VM

resource  "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension"  "install_ad" {

name  =  "install_ad"

# resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

virtual_machine_id  =  azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.dc01.id

publisher  =  "Microsoft.Compute"

type  =  "CustomScriptExtension"

type_handler_version  =  "1.9"

  

protected_settings  =  <<SETTINGS

{

"commandToExecute": "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${base64encode(data.template_file.ADDS.rendered)}')) | Out-File -filepath ADDS.ps1\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ADDS.ps1 -Domain_DNSName ${data.template_file.ADDS.vars.Domain_DNSName} -Domain_NETBIOSName ${data.template_file.ADDS.vars.Domain_NETBIOSName} -SafeModeAdministratorPassword ${data.template_file.ADDS.vars.SafeModeAdministratorPassword}"

}

SETTINGS

}

  

#Variable input for the ADDS.ps1 script

data  "template_file"  "ADDS" {

template  =  "${file("ADDS.ps1")}"

vars  =  {

Domain_DNSName  =  "${var.Domain_DNSName}"

Domain_NETBIOSName  =  "${var.netbios_name}"

SafeModeAdministratorPassword  =  "${var.SafeModeAdministratorPassword}"

}

}
```

**my variable.tf file :**

```
variable  "resource_group" {

type  =  string

description  =  "Resource group name"

default  =  "demoresourcegroupvk"

}

  

variable  "location" {

type  =  string

description  =  "RG and resources location"

default  =  "East US"

}

  

variable  "win_username" {

description  =  "Windows node username"

type  =  string

sensitive  =  false

}

  

variable  "win_userpass" {

description  =  "Windows node password"

type  =  string

sensitive  =  true

default  =  "enter your password"

}

  

variable  "Domain_DNSName" {

description  =  "FQDN for the Active Directory forest root domain"

type  =  string

sensitive  =  false

}

  

variable  "netbios_name" {

description  =  "NETBIOS name for the AD domain"

type  =  string

sensitive  =  false

}

  

variable  "SafeModeAdministratorPassword" {

description  =  "Password for AD Safe Mode recovery"

type  =  string

sensitive  =  true

default  =  "enter your password"

}
```

**my powershell script ADDS.ps1 :**

```
[CmdletBinding()]

  

param

(

[Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Domain_DNSName,

[Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Domain_NETBIOSName,

[Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [String]$SafeModeAdministratorPassword

)

  

$SMAP  =  ConvertTo-SecureString  -AsPlainText  $SafeModeAdministratorPassword  -Force

  

Install-windowsfeature  -name  AD-Domain-Services  -IncludeManagementTools

Install-ADDSForest  -CreateDnsDelegation:$false  -DatabasePath  "C:\Windows\NTDS"  -DomainMode  "WinThreshold"  -DomainName  $Domain_DNSName  -DomainNetbiosName  $Domain_NETBIOSName  -ForestMode  "WinThreshold"  -InstallDns:$true  -LogPath  "C:\Windows\NTDS"  -NoRebootOnCompletion:$false  -SysvolPath  "C:\Windows\SYSVOL"  -Force:$true  -SkipPreChecks  -SafeModeAdministratorPassword  $SMAP
```

**Note :** The Powershell file must be stored in the same directory where we save the main.tf and variable.tf are stored.

**Output :**

https://i.imgur.com/Pb7oi4K.png

https://i.imgur.com/zrAXObi.png

By this we can execute a PowerShell script using azurerm_virtual_machine_extension